# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement copy (from -r requirements.txt (line 10))

Tags: python, deep-learning, pip, reinforcement-learning

My server's conditions:

CUDA: 10, cudnn: 7.6   GPU:NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080Ti  system: Ubuntu18.04

When I try to reproduce the repository *[A2C](https://github.com/grantsrb/PyTorch-A2C)*, I get an error. I tried many ways, but failed. How can I fix this?

Output:

```
(myconda) root@9eac5f8cc084:~/PyTorch-A2C# python3.6 -m pip install --user -r requirements.txt
Looking in indexes: https://repo.huaweicloud.com/repository/pypi/simple
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /root/miniconda3/envs/myconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.16.3)
Requirement already satisfied: torch in /root/miniconda3/envs/myconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.0.1.post2)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in /root/miniconda3/envs/myconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (4.25.0)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /root/miniconda3/envs/myconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: gym in /root/miniconda3/envs/myconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 6)) (0.12.1)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement copy
ERROR: No matching distribution found for copy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`copy` is part of the standard library and does not need to be installed as it already exists.

You can remove `copy` from line 10 in the requirements.txt and try again.

Comment: For what it's worth, the upstream project has removed this dependency now. You might want to `get pull origin master` to update your copy.